# Get an IP_ADDRESS_STRING from GetAdaptersAddresses()?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, networking

[GetAdaptersAddresses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will get you addresses in IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS format, which is defined as:

```
typedef struct _IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS {
  union {
    struct {
      ULONG Length;
      DWORD Flags;
    } ;
  } ;
  struct _IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS *Next;
  SOCKET_ADDRESS                     Address;
  IP_PREFIX_ORIGIN                   PrefixOrigin;
  IP_SUFFIX_ORIGIN                   SuffixOrigin;
  IP_DAD_STATE                       DadState;
  ULONG                              ValidLifetime;
  ULONG                              PreferredLifetime;
  ULONG                              LeaseLifetime;
  UINT8                              OnLinkPrefixLength;
} IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS, *PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS;
```

The only field that seems to suggest the human-readable IP address string is Address, which is a SOCKET_ADDRESS structure defined as:

```
typedef struct _SOCKET_ADDRESS {
  LPSOCKADDR lpSockaddr;
  INT        iSockaddrLength;
} SOCKET_ADDRESS, *PSOCKET_ADDRESS;
```

Which, in turn, uses another structure, SOCKADDR, defined as:

Sorry, it's way to complex to post here, as it varies depending on IPv4 vs. IPv6 and the Windows edition... so here is a link to the definition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740496%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

If you haven't gotten dizzy yet like I did and followed through this maze of definitions, you probably noticed that it's a nightmare to retrieve the good old dotted string style of an IP address, as it used to be much easier using [GetAdaptersInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28VS.85%29.aspx).

My question is: Is there a *truly* IP Helper function that can convert IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS to an IPv4 dotted string (or an IPv6 string)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GetIpAddrTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365949(v=VS.85).aspx) - the [returned data structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366845(v=VS.85).aspx) contains a DWORD `dwAddr` that is the IPv4 address.  The sample code on that first link should show you what you want.  Brief excerpt to show you what I mean:

```
if ( (dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable( pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0 )) != NO_ERROR ) { 
    printf("GetIpAddrTable failed with error %d\n", dwRetVal);
    if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwRetVal, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),       // Default language
                      (LPTSTR) & lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL)) {
        printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    }
    exit(1);
}

printf("\tNum Entries: %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->dwNumEntries);
for (i=0; i < (int) pIPAddrTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
    printf("\n\tInterface Index[%d]:\t%ld\n", i, pIPAddrTable->table[i].dwIndex);
    IPAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long) pIPAddrTable->table[i].dwAddr;
    printf("\tIP Address[%d]:     \t%s\n", i, inet_ntoa(IPAddr) );
```

The `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS` contains a `SOCKET_ADDRESS` in `Address`, which in turn contains a `LPSOCKADDR` in lpSockAddr - you can convert this to the ipv4 string form using [WSAAddressToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741516(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: @Steve, thanks but this is not really what I was looking for. GetAdaptersAddresses() provides so much more information -- for both IPv4 and IPv6 -- and I would like to stick to it per Microsoft's recommendation. All I am missing is a "translator" convenience function that would take IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS as a parameter and output a string. Instead of re-inventing the wheel and writing it myself, perhaps you know of such existing function? In the API itself or elsewhere, perhaps some sample?

Comment: @Android Eve - see edit, you can use `WSAAddressToString` for this.

Comment: Once again, you demonstrate an impressive knowledge of PSDK's IP Helper space. Thanks to your answer, I have been able to spot a few more related functions, notably RtlIpv4AddressToString() and RtlIpv6AddressToString() which, unfortunately exist in the WDK, not the PSDK. I will shortly mark your answer as accepted. Unless a newer answer suggests a function that does the same for *both* IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: @Android Eve - see the docs - "While the `inet_ntoa` function works only with IPv4 addresses, the `WSAAddressToString` function works with any socket address supported by a Winsock provider on the local computer including IPv6 addresses."

Comment: @Android Eve - you are welcome - 13 yrs at Microsoft should have taught me something, I guess

Comment: Adding one more comment, to memorize in one place a related useful piece of information I just noticed: The IN6_ADDR structure used inRtlIpv6AddressToString() and that's defined in the In6addr.h header file, is a member of the SOCKADDR indirectly returned by GetAdaptersAddresses(). So, if WSAAddressToString() weren't availbe, there would still be a way to convert the addresses return by GetAdaptersAddresses() to strings, without having to write everything from scratch.

Comment: @SteveTownsend I'm seeing strange behavior on a customer's system with GetIpAddrTable - some adapters don't show up. Is there a simple list of reasons for the differences?

Comment: Cross-reference for the question I asked @SteveTownsend above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573007/getipaddrtable-returned-adapter-list-differs-from-getadaptersaddresses

Comment: @Will - did you try `GetAdapterAddresses`?  It looks like the API I recommended is IPv4 only and increasingly outdated therefore. If you cannot resolve quickly I would get repro code together and post another question.

Comment: @SteveTownsend See the question I posted - yes that is the other function I'm working with.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the documentation for [SOCKADDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That leads us to the documentation for [SOCKADDR_STORAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is a helper struct for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Quote from the sockaddr documentation:

> Winsock functions using sockaddr are not *strictly interpreted* to be
>   pointers to a sockaddr structure. The structure is interpreted
>   differently in the context of different address families.

For ipv4, you can cast a sockaddr pointer to a sockaddr_in pointer and then access the IPv4 address information from there. Then you can use your favorite string builder to produce a dotted-quad formatted string.

```
sockaddr_in* address = (sockaddr_in*) temp->Address.lpSockaddr;
uint32_t ipv4 = address->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
// First octet:  address->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1
// Second octet: address->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2
// Third octet:  address->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3
// Fourth octet: address->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4
```

I would imagine that you can also cast the address for ipv6 in a similar way given the struct definitions (copied below).

```
struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in {
        short   sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct  in_addr sin_addr;
        char    sin_zero[8];
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
        short   sin6_family;
        u_short sin6_port;
        u_long  sin6_flowinfo;
        struct  in6_addr sin6_addr;
        u_long  sin6_scope_id;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `_SOCKET_ADDRESS.lpSockaddr` and `_SOCKET_ADDRESS.iSockaddrLength` as `lpsaAddress` and `dwAddressLength` arguments to [`WSAAddressToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741516(v=vs.85).aspx) function. `WSAAddressToString` will do necessary conversion for you, no need to dig deeper.

```
function SOCKET_ADDRESS_ToString(const Addr: SOCKET_ADDRESS): String;
var
  Len: DWORD;
begin
  if (Addr.lpSockaddr = nil) or (Addr.iSockaddrLength <= 0) then
  begin
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  Len := 0;
  WSAAddressToString(Addr.lpSockaddr, Addr.iSockaddrLength, nil, nil, Len);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  if WSAAddressToString(Addr.lpSockaddr, Addr.iSockaddrLength, nil, PChar(Result), Len) = 0 then
    SetLength(Result, Len - 1)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```