# GetIpAddrTable Returned Adapter List Differs from GetAdaptersAddresses

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

### Different Adapter Lists Returned

I would like to know the root cause of why `GetIpAddrTable` would return fewer network adapters than `GetAdaptersAddresses`. Candidate reasons are given below (updated per answers).

### Candidate Reasons

- *IPv6 adapters*: These will only show up for `GetAdaptersAddresses`. In this example I have a case of an adapter with link-local IP addresses for both IPv4 and IPv6 that does not show up in output from GetIpAddrTable.

### Background

I'm investigating a problem with the `GetIpAddrTable` function on a specific Dell laptop running Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium (version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601). The system in question is unable to detect certain network adapters via `GetIpAddrTable`. Diagnostic results are given below.

Can anyone explain why I might see such wildly different results from these two functions? We've been using `GetIpAddrTable` for close to two years without any problems.

### Documentation Check

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `GetIpAddrTable` indicates that link state detection may cause problems for XP, but it does not give any reasons why adapters would not show up at all. *It appears* that virtual adapters are not included, but our device is not a virtual adapter (it is Ethernet over USB).

> On Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, the IPv4 addresses returned
>   by the GetIpAddrTable function are not affected by the media sensing
>   capability of the TCP/IP stack on a local computer. The GetIpAddrTable
>   function returns only valid IPv4 addresses.

In the testing I've conducted on this system we have a valid connection, but it is only reported by `GetAdaptersAddresses`, not `GetIpAddrTable`. I suspect that Windows thinks the adapter is not valid, but I'm not sure what to test to confirm this theory. Packets are flowing to and from the device, it just isn't visible in the IPv4 address mapping table.

### Implementation Details

- We use the [Belcarra USBLAN ethernet gadget driver](http://www.belcarra.com/p/usblan.html) (customized for our company)
- We expect our device to register via DHCP for the host and device
- The driver provides DHCP
- Our first host adapter is given 169.254.142.9
- Our first device adapter is given 169.254.142.10
- Traffic to our device is not routed externally (link-local)

### GetIpAddrTable Results

Normally we would expect to see two or three network adapters and never the loopback adapter. Perhaps the presence of 127.0.0.1 in this list is part of the problem - it isn't normally observed on a working machine.

- *Adapter 1: Software Loopback Interface 1*
- *Adapter 2: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030*

### GetAdaptersAddresses Results

I've listed the adapters returned by this function in the order that they were returned. Matching adapters from the first call are *emphasized*. The only adapter not present in ipconfig output is in **bold**.

- Adapter 1: USBLAN Adapter
- Adapter 2: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
- Adapter 3: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
- *Adapter 4: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030*
- Adapter 5: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- ***Adapter 6: Software Loopback Interface 1***
- Adapter 7: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
- Adapter 8: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
- Adapter 9: Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
- Adapter 10: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
- Adapter 11: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
- Adapter 12: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5

### ipconfig /all Results

Notice that the software loopback adapter is the only one not present - which indicates that ipconfig is using the second function or a similar interface internally.

- Adapter 1: USBLAN Adapter
- Adapter 2: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
- Adapter 3: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
- *Adapter 4: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030*
- Adapter 5: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- Adapter 6: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
- Adapter 7: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
- Adapter 8: Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
- Adapter 9: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
- Adapter 10: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
- Adapter 11: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5

### Cross-Referencing Results

It appears that the `ipconfig /all` command is returning the same data as `GetAdaptersAddresses` with the exception of the software loopback interface. I am currently looking at switching our library to use `GetAdaptersAddresses` in order to plug this issue, but I'm concerned about why `GetIpAddrTable` is not returning expected results. Thanks in advance for any input!

### Related Questions

- [Get an IP_ADDRESS_STRING from GetAdaptersAddresses()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989446/get-an-ip-address-string-from-getadaptersaddresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetIpAddrTable()` only returns IPv4 interfaces.

`GetAdaptersAddresses()` returns IPv4 and/or IPv6 adapters, and single adapter can have multiple IP addresses assigned to it.

You are comparing apples and oranges, and wondering why you have fewer apples than oranges.

Comment: Except in this case the adapter in question is not an IPv6-only adapter. We register an IPv4 address (see comments in question about the IP address assignment). We only use the IPv4 link-local interface for it.

Comment: Marking this as the only viable answer - it seems logical.

Comment: Update: I've now confirmed that this is the actual reason. Querying for IPv4 interfaces via GetAdaptersAddresses also skips our adapter on the system in question.