# What is a Valid IPv4 Address for GetIpAddrTable

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I would like to know what a "valid IPv4 address" is in the *context* of the win32 `GetIpAddrTable` function call. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that this function does not return invalid IPv4 addresses on Vista and above. It does not explain how it determines validity.

> On Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, the IPv4 addresses returned
>   by the GetIpAddrTable function are not affected by the media sensing
>   capability of the TCP/IP stack on a local computer. *The GetIpAddrTable
>   function returns only valid IPv4 addresses.*

I am digging into a problem where a call to this function is not returning the address for a functioning adapter. The adapter uses the driver's DHCP server to assign a link-local IP address. On most systems this works fine. On a specific customer system, it does not.

Ping and traffic tests work fine and the adapter shows up in output from `GetAdaptersAddresses`. My other question seems to indicate that the only difference should be IPv6 support. The adapter in question receives a link-local IPv6 address as well, but that shouldn't prevent it from showing up in `GetIpAddrTable` output should it?

### Cross-Reference

- [GetIpAddrTable Returned Adapter List Differs from GetAdaptersAddresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573007/getipaddrtable-returned-adapter-list-differs-from-getadaptersaddresses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer: It does exactly what it says it does - it returns connected interfaces which are running IPv4.

I've now confirmed that GetAdaptersAddresses also skips our network adapter when limiting to IPv4 interfaces. So it appears that there's a problem between the driver and Windows in identifying as an IPv4 interface.